# Format Specifies in C for float datatype

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    system("color FC");
const float i=23.1234234;
printf("%5.4f",i); 
getch();
return 0;
}
```

In above code , while printing float data type `%5.4` format specifier is used. 
I understood that `.4` is used to get four numbers after decimal but whats the use of `5` before `.4`

Answer (score 2):

The `5` is the length specifier. In this case, the printed float will take up at least 5 spaces. If it is shorter than that, leading spaces will be used.

(Though because of the precision `4`, it will always be at least 6 characters long; the length modifier `5` in this case is a no-op.)

See [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: I tried 
`const float i=3.121111111111;`
`printf("%2f",i); `

But I am getting `3.121111`

Comment: *at least* that length. Try `printf("%20f",3)`

Comment: When I am adding `20`, Its just putting `20` white spaces before `3.000000`

Comment: @AkashSharma, it pads the number to fit at least that length.

Comment: yes what is wrong then ? 20 whitespaces are not put before 3, 20 is the space including 3.000000.

Answer (score 1):

5 is used  to right justify the output by 5  places i.e. the last digit will occur 5 places from cursor's initial position, if possible.

It is effective only when the length ( including the decimal ) is smaller than what is mentioned in the specifier.

e.g. printf("%5.4f",i);

till the specifier at the place of 5 is smaller than or equal than the length of the output

i.e 2(before decimal) + 4(after decimal, as chosen ) + 1 (the decimal  itself) =7 , it has

no effect.

It will have effect here if it is at least 8.

At 7 it does what it should but you won's see any spaces.

Comment: I don't know how u get it. I don't get it,

Answer (score 0):

`5` is used to right justify the output by `5` places. Since the output is `10` character long so the effect is not seen. Now try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
const float i=23.1234234;

printf("%f\n",i);
printf("%5.4f\n",i);
printf("%7.4f\n",i);
printf("%10.4f\n",i);
printf("%12.5f",i);

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
23.1234234
23.1234
23.1234 
    23.1234
      23.1234
```